Help me choose a verb. — If biologists say people belong to mammals, then biologists "VERB" people to mammals. — What verb would be natural here?
I need a verb meaning something like "to ascribe something into/to/in some category".
my own sentences:
(1a) Biologists say people belong to mammals.
(2a) Some linguists say "not" belongs to adverbs.
I want to rewrite these sentences but don't know what verb to use.
(1b) Biologists "VERB" people to mammals.
(2b) Some linguists "VERB" "not" to adverbs.
What verb would be natural here?
"Attribute", "ascribe", "refer", "relate", "put", "place" or something else?

In my opinion, a native speaker would say:
(1b) Biologists classify people as mammals.
(2b) Some linguists categorise "not" as an adverb.
